# Regular expression for Email validation which detect ".com.com"

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Validate email address in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

I'm having some trouble with validating email address client side using Javascript. After a lot of searching I found a regular expression which is as follows:-

```
/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$
```

It was working fine with most email ids I have tested with. But suddenly I discovered that it's also saying email's with `.com.com` like extensions, which is a serious bug for me.

How my question is that how I can modify the mentioned regular expression which will invalid `.com.com` also.

I should also mention that i have also tried with many other regular expressions but they all seem to have this same mentioned problem...

Thanks...

Comment: *why* is this valid extension a problem for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address

Comment: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: `com.com` is a real domain name. People could have email addresses there.

Comment: Please don't use a regex that excludes using a + in the first portion of the email address. Fluent validation uses this regex and I haven't run into any problems with using it in production: http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1448&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will invalidate any address ending in `.com.com`:

`/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@(?![A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.com\.com)([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

This will also invalidate those ending in `@com.com`:

`/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@(?!(?:[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.)?com\.com)([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

Finally, this will invalidate those ending in *any* repetition, eg, .net.net, .au.au, etc:

`/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@(?!(?:[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\.)?([A-Za-z]{2,4})\.\2)([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
function verifyEmail(){
var status = false;     
var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
     if (document.myform.email1.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
          alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
     }
     else{
         status = true;
     }
     return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function emailCheck (emailStr) {
 var checkTLD=1;
   var knownDomsPat=/^(com|net|org|edu|int|mil|gov|arpa|biz|aero|name|coop|info|pro|museum)$/;
  var emailPat=/^(.+)@(.+)$/;
  var specialChars="\\(\\)><@,;:\\\\\\\"\\.\\[\\]";
  var validChars="\[^\\s" + specialChars + "\]";
  var quotedUser="(\"[^\"]*\")";
  var ipDomainPat=/^\[(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\]$/;
  var atom=validChars + '+';

  var word="(" + atom + "|" + quotedUser + ")";
  var userPat=new RegExp("^" + word + "(\\." + word + ")*$");
  var domainPat=new RegExp("^" + atom + "(\\." + atom +")*$");
 var matchArray=emailStr.match(emailPat);
  if (matchArray==null) {
  alert("Email address seems incorrect (check @ and .'s)");
return false;
}
```

The official email check method of my ISP website. 
No copyright on this. So you can use it.

Comment: i think it was generated by Microsoft Visual Studio.